# Is there any way to use POI to get Word text runs that are nested inside of an sdt / sdtContent element?

Tags: apache-poi

For a given paragraph using POI, I'm trying to do something with all the Runs contained in the paragraph. The following code gets the runs that are nested directly inside the paragraph element, but if they are nested inside of an sdt/sdtContent element, the runs are stored in a private bodyElements variable with no public getter.

```
final Iterator<XWPFParagraph> it = doc.getParagraphsIterator();
while( it.hasNext() ) {
    final XWPFParagraph next = it.next();
    for( IRunElement iRun : next.getIRuns() ) {
        if( iRun instanceof XWPFSDT sdt ) {
            if( sdt.getContent() instanceof XWPFSDTContent sdtContent ) {
                sdtContent.bodyElements; //This has the runs, but it's private, so I can't access them
            }
        } else {
            //Do stuff with the run
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some way to recurse down to get all the runs? I'm using POI 5.2.5

Comment: If you think you need a not public class member, then what about using java reflection to get it?

Comment: Reflection requires the JRE to be launched with -add-opens parameters and that is hard to arrange for the environments I’m running in.

Comment: Then there are only three possibilities. Either you file a change request to Apache POI to provide public access to what you need. But be patient then. Or you get part of the Apache POI developer team and hope your code changes get accepted. Or you create a fork of that project and do that yourself by changing code of  `XWPFSDTContent.java` before compiling your fork.